# Objective-C Weather API

Tags: objective-c, api, weather, weather-api

How do I fetch current weather-**temperature** (based on ZipCode), using XCode with Objective-C? Is there an API (framework/library)? I can't seem to find one using Google. With the project I'm working on right now, all I need to do is simply fetch an integer (e.g., degrees fahrenheit).

**This is for Mac OS X, not iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are five different ones you can look into.

http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/04/15/5-weather-apis-from-weatherbug-to-weather-channel/

Do any fit your needs?

Comment: These are good, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use [World Weather Online](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/).  It's free and pretty comprehensive.  It will fit your needs, of course. [Here](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather-feed.aspx) is the local weather API, where you can input zip codes.

Answer (score 0):

OpenWeatherMap gets my vote. I wrote a wrapper for it so that you don't have to touch the JSON. The link is here if it helps - http://jonathanfield.me/objective-c-openweathermap-api-wrapper/